# What is the best bo staff for an 8-year-old for competitions?

Tags: karate, weapons, drills, bo-staff

What would be the best bo staff for an 8-year-old child to use in competitions. The bamboo toothpick is much too heavy for him. Would anyone recommend the fiberglass bo staff?

Answer (score 1):

Century Martial Arts advertises their smallest bamboo toothpick starting at 12 oz. That would be the 50" (4' 2") variety. The lightest fiberglass I could find in a non-exhaustive search was still 1 lb. 5 oz.

If that's too heavy, the student should train so it is not too heavy. Lifting weights with proper form and properly trained supervision can be a safe and efficient way to increase overall strength -- a [standard recommendation for children beginning reasonable weighted exercises](http://pediatricinsider.wordpress.com/2010/12/18/weightlifting-for-children-teens-and-adults/) is to start with no weight (just the bar) and perform the exercise to learn good form, then increase just 1 or 2 pounds at a time.

Comment: We're just going to have to disagree on that. Cheers.